# Wordpress php get result from sql where special character

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, character

I have this code

```
$ntimes = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT Count(*) FROM wp_comp_review_list where email = $key->email");
```

What I was trying to do is count the number of emails `where email = "sample@gmail.com"`. Wherein the email to compare is generated from another foreach loop.

I am having the following error:

> "WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1]"

I tried the by comparing names that has spaces. I got the same error because of the space.

Any tips on how to use `WHERE` with special characters?

Comment: You error is quite clear: you have invalid SQL statement. You should fix it by properly substituting variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email is a string so you should use quotes, `where email = '$key->email'` though you're also open to SQL injection, if not it's better safe then hacked..

So you should use prepared statements instead using [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare('
        SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM wp_comp_review_list 
        WHERE email = %s', 
        [
            $key->email
        ]
    )
);
```

This should also work using [esc_sql()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql), though avoid when you can:

```
<?php
$email = esc_sql($key->email);
$wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM wp_comp_review_list 
    WHERE email = '{$email}'"
);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this. I have no idea about sql injenction though.. but i will use your code for security.

Comment: thanks np, i have no idea about wordpress ;p just sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$ntimes = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT Count(*) FROM wp_comp_review_list where email = '$key->email'");
```

Since your `$key->email` has space, it is no more a single word and next thing after space is considered as SQL command (which is it not)

Answer (score 0):

You miss quote `''` from the condition:

```
$ntimes = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT Count(*) FROM wp_comp_review_list where email = '$key->email'");
```

Comment: Wow! that worked. I never tried it before. Thanks very much sir

Comment: @TimothyFigueroa It opens you to SQLi though.

Comment: When you check in a condition a char, varchar, text etc... You need tonuse quote remember